# Create variable string for request API payload

Tags: python-3.x, string, request, python-requests, payload

I have a list of URLs that all refer to images. I want to loop through the list and call a [face recognition API](https://rapidapi.com/inferdo/api/face-detection6) that accepts these URLs. To call the API, I need to provide the payload dictionary. However, the example code from the API requires the following form for the payload dictionary:

```
payload = "{\"url\":\"https://inferdo.com/img/face-3.jpg\",\"accuracy_boost\":3}"
```

The URL in this example payload dictionary would look like this in my list:

```
list_of_urls = ["https://inferdo.com/img/face-3.jpg", ...]
```

How can I insert the entries of my list into the payload dictionary with a for loop?

I tried to use a "regular" payload dictionary, but it did not work:

```
for url_path in list_of_urls:
    payload = {'url' : url_path,'accuracy_boost':3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the API documentation and found you need to send the payload as JSON. Something like this will do the job:

```py
import requests
import json

endpoints = {
    'face': 'https://face-detection6.p.rapidapi.com/img/face'
    'face_age_gender': 'https://face-detection6.p.rapidapi.com/img/face-age-gender'
}

urls = [
    'https://inferdo.com/img/face-3.jpg'
]

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'face-detection6.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'YOUR-API-KEY',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json'
}

for url in urls:
    payload = {
        'url': url,
        'accuracy_boost': 3
    }

    r = requests.post(
        endpoints.get('face'), # or endpoint.get('face_age_gender')
        data=json.dumps(payload),
        headers=headers
    )

    if r.ok:
        # do something with r.content or r.json()
```

I hope it helps.